# Why isn't the count incrementing properly?

Tags: python

I have a regular value that starts at zero. And I want to check if the value is three or higher. However, it isn't working.

```
    vowel_count = 0
    vowel = False
    double = False
    auto_naughty = False
    for index, letter in enumerate(item):
        if letter in vowels:
            vowel_count += 1
        if vowel_count >= 3:
            vowel = True
```

It increases by 1, then stops, as shown in the output.

```
1
1
1
```

And here is the input if you guys are wondering

```
'ugknbfddgicrmopn'
```

**EDIT**
Someone asked me for the full code, so I am showing it. Don't close the question.

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

nice_strings = 0

for item in strings:
    vowel_count = 0
    vowel = False
    double = False
    auto_naughty = False
    for index, letter in enumerate(item):
        if letter in vowels:
            vowel_count += 1
            print(vowel_count)
        if vowel_count >= 3:
            vowel = True
        if (letter + item[index]) == (letter + letter):
            double = True
        if (letter + item[index]) == (letter + naughty_dict[letter]):
            auto_naughty = True
    if not auto_naughty:
        if double:
            if vowel:
                nice_strings += 1
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: That's not the full code since strings is undefined. Similar for naughty_dict

Comment: If I add strings = ["ugknbfddgicrmopn"] and remove all the code related to "naught_dict" this runs fine. We can't help you solve the problem if you can't post a reproducible example.

Comment: I suspect you wanted `strings` to be `['ugknbfddgicrmopn']`, i.e. a list of strings, but instead set it to just `'ugknbfddgicrmopn'`, i.e. a single string.  So when iterating, `item` takes on the individual characters, as single-character strings.  So each `item`is a single character, and `vowel_count` can never be greater than one.  But there's a lot of guesswork here since you refused to post a complete example that can be reproduced.  Why?  If I put your code in a file exactly as posted, it will not run, because it's incomplete.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I know why. You are inputting `strings` as a single string. The line `for item in strings:` is therefore iterating over each letter, rather than over the full string. Just put the string in a list, or if you're only going to do this for one string remove the initial for loop.

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

nice_strings = 0

strings = ["ugknbfddgicrmopn"]

for item in strings:
    vowel_count = 0
    vowel = False
    double = False
    auto_naughty = False
    for index, letter in enumerate(item):
        if letter in vowels:
            vowel_count += 1
            print(vowel_count)
        if vowel_count >= 3:
            vowel = True
        if (letter + item[index]) == (letter + letter):
            double = True
```